# Form vue.js on submit, how to link to external website with custom id? "error: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuex

I just started to learn VUE and how to use it in a rails project. In my case I'm trying to create an embedded javascript which stores can implement on their website, so their customers can look for available items available for that store.

The goal is that the embedded javascript shows a form with 2 dates `arrival` and `departure`. On submitting the form, the visitor of the store website should be redirected to my app, which then shows available items belonging to the store the user came from.

**Question**
I am able to make it work with an action with a fixed id (`see also the commented out code below`), but I don't know how to add the link dynamically (e.g. find store id belonging to the referrer link that should match the `booking_url`, and redirect to the `../park_availability page` of my app).

**Attempt 1 + error messages:**

**general idea:** I tried creating a `submit method` on the form of file `javascript/app.vue` , which consequently should load the function `searchAccommodations` in `javascript/store.js` on submit.

error messages

```
vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"

found in

---> <App> at app/javascript/app.vue
       <Root>
warn    @   vue.esm.js:628
logError    @   vue.esm.js:1893
globalHandleError   @   vue.esm.js:1888
handleError @   vue.esm.js:1848
invokeWithErrorHandling @   vue.esm.js:1871
invoker @   vue.esm.js:2188
original._wrapper   @   vue.esm.js:7565
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
    at VueComponent.submit (app.vue:36)
    at submit (app.vue?0d7f:13)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js:1863)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (vue.esm.js:2188)
    at HTMLFormElement.original._wrapper (vue.esm.js:7565)
logError @ vue.esm.js:1897
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js:1888
handleError @ vue.esm.js:1848
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.esm.js:1871
invoker @ vue.esm.js:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.esm.js:7565
```

javascript/app.vue (form shops should insert)

```
<template>

<!-- For reference Working link commented out below -->
    <!-- <form id="myapp-reservation-form" action="https://www.myapp.eu/parks/18/park_availability" ref="form" method="get"> -->


<form @submit.prevent="submit" id="myapp-reservation-form" ref="form">

    <div class="myapp-reservation-form-item">
      <h6>Arrival</h6>
      <input type="date" id="arrival" name="arrival" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="myapp-reservation-form-item">
      <h6>Departure</h6>
      <input type="date" id="departure" name="departure" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="myapp-reservation-form-item">
      <h6></h6>
        <button class="btn search-accommodations-button">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods:{
    submit(){
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)
 this.Redirect(`https://www.myapp.eu/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/park_availability/`);
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.state.$store)
    this.$store.dispatch("searchAccommodations", formData)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

console.log(this)

```
VueComponent {_uid: 1, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
$attrs: (...)
$listeners: (...)
$data: (...)
$props: (...)
$isServer: (...)
$ssrContext: (...)
_uid: 1
_isVue: true
$options: {parent: Vue, _parentVnode: VNode, propsData: undefined, _parentListeners: undefined, _renderChildren: undefined, …}
_renderProxy: Proxy {_uid: 1, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
_self: VueComponent {_uid: 1, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
$parent: Vue {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue, …}
$root: Vue {_uid: 0, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: Vue, …}
$children: []
$refs: {form: form#myapp-reservation-form}
_watcher: Watcher {vm: VueComponent, deep: false, user: false, lazy: false, sync: false, …}
_inactive: null
_directInactive: false
_isMounted: true
_isDestroyed: false
_isBeingDestroyed: false
_events: {}
_hasHookEvent: false
_vnode: VNode {tag: "form", data: {…}, children: Array(5), text: undefined, elm: form#myapp-reservation-form, …}
_staticTrees: (3) [VNode, VNode, VNode]
$vnode: VNode {tag: "vue-component-1", data: {…}, children: undefined, text: undefined, elm: form#myapp-reservation-form, …}
$slots: {}
$scopedSlots: {$stable: true, $key: undefined, $hasNormal: false}
_c: ƒ (a, b, c, d)
$createElement: ƒ (a, b, c, d)
_watchers: [Watcher]
submit: ƒ ()
_data: {__ob__: Observer}
$el: form#myapp-reservation-form
get $attrs: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set $attrs: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get $listeners: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set $listeners: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Vue
```

javascript/packs/embed.js (used to load initial form shown in app.vue)

```
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from '../app.vue'
import store from '../store'


const event = (typeof Turbolinks == "object" && Turbolinks.supported) ? "turbolinks:load" : 'DOMContentLoaded';

document.addEventListener(event, () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#myapp-reservation-form')
  store.dispatch('loadComments')
  const app = new Vue({
    el,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  })
})
```

javascript/store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)


const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    accommodation_categories:[]
  },

  mutations: {
    load(state, accommodation_categories){
      state.accommodation_categories = accommodation_categories
    },
  },

  actions: {

    async loadComments({ commit }){
      let booking_url = window.location.href
      fetch(`https://www.myapp.eu/api/v1/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/form_availability/`,{
        headers: {accept: 'application/json'}
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => commit('load', data))
    },

    async searchAccommodations({commit}, formData){
      let booking_url = window.location.href
      fetch(`https://www.myapp.eu/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/park_availability/`,{
        headers: {accept: 'application/json'},
        method: "get",
        body: formData,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => commit('load', data))
    }
  }
})



window.store = store

export default store
```

**Attempt 2 + error messages:**
Following the tip of @ellisdod, I tried moving the initial store.dispatch('loadComments') into the created hook of my component.

error message

```
vue.esm.js:628 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.Redirect is not a function"

found in

---> <App> at app/javascript/app.vue
       <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js:628
logError @ vue.esm.js:1893
globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js:1888
handleError @ vue.esm.js:1848
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.esm.js:1871
invoker @ vue.esm.js:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.esm.js:7565
```

```
vue.esm.js:1897 TypeError: this.Redirect is not a function
    at VueComponent.submit (app.vue:32)
    at submit (app.vue?0d7f:13)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js:1863)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (vue.esm.js:2188)
    at HTMLFormElement.original._wrapper (vue.esm.js:7565)
```

javascript/app.vue (script change)

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {}
  },
  methods:{
    submit(){
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)
this.Redirect(`https://www.myapp.eu/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/park_availability/`);
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.$store.state)
    this.$store.dispatch("searchAccommodations", formData)
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadComments')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the initial `store.dispatch('loadComments')` into the created hook of your component.

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {}
  },
  methods:{
    submit(){
    let formData = new FormData(this.$refs.form)
this.Redirect(`https://www.myapp.eu/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/park_availability/`);
    console.log(this)
    console.log(this.$store.state)
    this.$store.dispatch("searchAccommodations", formData)
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadComments')
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help @ellisdod. Unfortunately, this resulted into another error message which I included in my question. Given these errors I think the problem might lie   with ```this``` (not sure though).

Comment: Ok looks like the issue is with Redirect, is this supposed to be a vue plugin? If you are directing to a page within your app use vue router `this.$router.push('url')` https://router.vuejs.org/. If its to a different site use `window.open('url')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thanks, think we (you) are on to something!:) The link is outside of the app, as external website will link to myapp. I tried ```window.open(`https://www.myapp.eu/parks/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/park_availability/`);```, but I am not able to add the id of the park (which should be identified by matching ```window.location.href``` with @park.booking_url. Not sure how to do this though..

Comment: could you upload an example url?

Comment: Sure the link to my app would be something like this ```https://www.myapp.eu/parks/{park_id}/park_availability/``` and the ```booking_url``` of a store (which is the place on which the form is posted) is something like ```https://www.store.com```. Consequently I would like to compare the form url with the url from the form and come up with an ```park_id``` (if possible).

Comment: You can access the url from within Vue with `this.$route.path` and then use regex to extract the park_id. Or (better) install vue router and create a route like `{path: 'https://www.myapp.eu/parks/:park_id/park_availability/', component: ParkLandingPage}` then access with `this.$route.params.park_id`